# Qt-based Face Recognition Application

Tags: linux, qt, opencv, image-processing, fedora

Im trying to compile a Qt project based on the [example given here](https://github.com/sun11/QTFaceRec).

I managed to compile without errors, but during execution there are errors. I'm getting these errors in pop up windows:

-open /dev/dsp error

-init failed

-start capture failed

-get frame failed

Moreover, the output displays:

sh: line 0: .:setqt4env:file not found
Trying open file
Could not open File! Error code: 5
/home/QFaceRec/QTFaceRecForPC exited with code 0

SIGSEGV Error when debugging with Qt Creator.

I have googled, answers are due to the application tries to access memory illegally.
Therefore, I try to execute in su - / root, but the run time error remain unsolved.

Im trying to compile and run the code in fedora with qt creator without the GPIO and serial port setting.

Anyone got any ideas to my problem? or knows how to compile the qt code in the link above

Comment: the link above is useless. show your code instead !

Comment: Hi, the code is too lengthy, so you may refer here https://github.com/sun11/QTFaceRec

Comment: again, useless. also it seems, you could compile it, and you're getting runtime errors now ?

Comment: contact the application developper

Comment: i'm sorry, i have very surface programming knowledge and im quite new to qt application too. could you tell some hints?

Comment: Hi UmNyobe, the owner is inactive. berak: exactly, i managed to compile, but it show the errors in prompt-out gui, and the window is empty

Comment: Maybe you can try with serial port settings? Or, are you sure that you are disabled them correctly? It is trying to open something 'open /dev/dsp error'.

Comment: It gives error when running 'setqt4env'. What does that do? Try to run that piece alone, apparently it cant set Qt 4 environment..

Comment: i have removed the serial codes during compiling the code. besides, i also commented out setqt4env, but when executing, still getting the errors -open /dev/dsp error

-init failed

-start capture failed

-get frame failed       the erros are in sequence, after press ok, it shows others, which i listed above

Answer (score 0):

> Answers are due to the application tries to access memory illegally. Therefore, I try to execute in su - / root

Do not do that! The illegal memory access is not a matter of permissions, it's a matter of the software having bugs. By running it as root, there's a possibility that those bugs will wreck your system.